# RoomDatabase Insert doesnt work and no error to find why

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, insert, android-room

i am using room database
when i insert data, i can not read it again
and i dont know what is the problem because there is no error for sql

the question is  what is the problem and how sql throws exertion

**Entity**

```
@Entity(tableName = "boards_table")
class BoardModel {
    @PrimaryKey
    var  Id = ""
    var Title =""
}
```

id is not auto increase becaus it already  created, i am reading an API

**DAO**

```
@Dao
interface BoardDAO {


    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun addBoard(board:BoardModel)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM boards_table")
    fun readAllData(): LiveData<List<BoardModel>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM boards_table")
        suspend fun deleteAllBoard()
    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteBoard(board:BoardModel)



}
```

**write in activity**

```
private lateinit var boardDao:BoardDAO
appDb = NimaDatabase.getDatabase(this)

// tempBoardlist from api and it is OK
for (board in tempBoardlist){
  GlobalScope.launch {
    boardDao.addBoard(board.toBoardModel())
   }
 }
```

**read in activity**

`var boardlist = boardDao.readAllData().value`

i used @Throws(SQLException::class) but not worked

```
// this works fine 
// class to get from API easily
class board() {
    val _id: String = ""
    val title: String = ""
}

//Covert it to BoardModel
fun board.toBoardModel() : BoardModel
{
    val b =  BoardModel()
    b.Id = _id
    b.Title = title
    return b
}
```

Comment: can you please put the code where you are create insert data model.

Comment: @HanifShaikh i am not using viewModel and repository

Comment: no, i ask about where you create you model for insert data I want to see that

Comment: also i want to see toBoardModel this one

Comment: @HanifShaikh Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Room entity must have access to it, You can make sure Room has access to a field either by making it public or by providing getter and setter methods for it.

Please read [room defining-data](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data)

You need to define the `data class` to have access to setter and getter methods.

```
@Entity(tableName = "boards_table")
data class BoardModel(
@PrimaryKey
val  id : Long,
val title : String
 )
```

In Activity, it's recommended to use activity lifecycleScope to launch coroutines.
Read [Use Kotlin coroutines with lifecycle-aware components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
   // for loop must be in coroutine scope
   for(data in list) boardDao.insert(data) 
}
```

This `var boardlist = boardDao.readAllData().value` it will return `null`

[LiveData](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) is an observable data holder. You need to register as an observer.

In Activity:

```
    // Create the observer which updates the UI.
    val nameObserver = Observer<List<BoardModel>> { list ->
        // Update the UI Hire.
        if(list != null) // update list, recyclerview, etc...
    }
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        boardDao.readAllData().observe(this@MainActivity,nameObserver)
    }
```

Comment: insert works now, how to update myBoardList in Observer, myBoardList is liveData<list<BoardModel>>

Comment: Great. Generally, LiveData delivers updates only when Room data changes, and only to active observers. when you insert, update, and delete from Room, the myBoardList in Observer will observe a new list automatically.

Comment: Observer calls multiple times, if result list size is 10, it will be called 10 times!

Comment: if you are observe in Fragment, use `viewLifecycleOwner` instead of `this@MainActivity`.

Comment: also try to add distinctUntilChanged in `live.distinctUntilChanged().observe(...)`

Comment: im am using this in mainActivity and get this error: unresolved reference viewLifecycleOwner

Answer (score 0):

```
fun board.toBoardModel() : BoardModel
{
    val b =  BoardModel()
    b.Title = title
    return b
}
```

Try this one

Comment: not working, why not pass id? object comes from api via uniqe id, and need to store it